# In a React Component Class where do you declare a websocket connection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

I'm trying to use a websocket connection in a component class, but I need to declare it seperately from the function that opens it. Is there a way to declare universally or in state so that I can access the open websocket, so that I can close it before opening up another.

I have tried declaring at the top of the page with imports

```
const ws = new WebSocket("wss://ws-feed.pro.coinbase.com");
```

Also making it an attribute of the class:

```
lass App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.ws = new WebSocket("wss://ws-feed.pro.coinbase.com");
  this.state = {
  
  }
}
```

but it will always throw the error: 'ws' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: What will "throw the error"? In the latter case, you'd have to use `this.ws`, of course.

Comment: Yes I am using "this.ws.onopen" but it simply fails to connect. It only connects if it is declared in the method I am using. But I need to close the connection in a different method.